# error TS2339: Property 'hometeam' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: angular

I am facing below errors when I compile my angular 2 project. I am new to angular 2 and can't seem to come to a conclusion about the resolution. I search the threads on SO similar to this but its not working.

1. error TS2339: Property 'hometeam' does not exist on type '{}'.
    hometeam is an object in my returned data. they why it's not considering as object.

This error is coming in multiple service calls that I am making. It's a MEAN stack application. Please have a look at screenshot....

[image]

**Code:**

```
this.authService.gettodaysmatches().subscribe((data:any) => {
          console.log("Data for today's matches coming up Admin panel...");
          console.log(data);

          this.todaysMatches = data;
          //this.matchId = this.todaysMatches._id;
          for(var i=0; i<this.todaysMatches.length; i++){             
              var hometeam = this.todaysMatches[i].hometeam.teamname;
              var awayteam = this.todaysMatches[i].awayteam.teamname;             

              var obj = {};
              obj.hometeam = hometeam;
              obj.awayteam = awayteam;           
              obj.matchid = this.todaysMatches[i]._id;

              this.todaysTeam.push(obj);
          }
      })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either create a custom type for `todaysMatches` - **TodaysMatches** and cast it:

```
this.authService.gettodaysmatches().subscribe((data:TodaysMatches) => {
<...>
```

Or use Typescript's lookup types and access properties like - `['prop']`:

```
this.authService.gettodaysmatches().subscribe((data:any) => {
          this.todaysMatches = data;
          for(var i=0; i<this.todaysMatches.length; i++){             
              var hometeam = this.todaysMatches[i]['hometeam']['teamname'];
              var awayteam = this.todaysMatches[i]['awayteam']['teamname'];             
<...>
```

p.s. the screenshot of the error shows a bunch of other Typescript related bugs that are not relevant to the code snippet you posted

Comment: tried second approach but it's not working....anything else i need to do apart from ['prop']

Comment: So `console.log(data);` doesnt print the `todaysMatches` object, right? Its an empty object?

Comment: right perfect... I found one more issue, I have declared var obj = {};and when I am putting obj.teamname it's showing error.... either i need to initialize key or i need to use ['prop']

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
// Api returned Type
export interface MatchModel{
  id: number;
  title: string;
  hometeam: string;
}
// Light Model.
export interface OtherModel {
  id: Number;
  title: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
  /**
   * Dummy observable to fake Api answer. Return Array of MatchModel
   */
  getDummyData(): Observable<MatchModel[]> {
    return Observable.create((obs) => {
        obs.next([
            {
              id: 1,
              title: "foo",
              hometeam: "bar"
            },
            {
              id: 2,
              title: "ksdof",
              hometeam: "koko"
            },
            {
              id: 3,
              title: "fokokoo",
              hometeam: "sdfsdf"
            }
        ]);
    });
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  providers: [ApiService],
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  public matchs: MatchModel[];
  public others: OtherModel[];

  constructor(private api: ApiService) {
    this.matchs = [];
    this.others = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.api.getDummyData().subscribe(matchs => {

        this.matchs = matchs;
        // We just map array of MatchModel to fit on OtherModel type.
        this.others = this.matchs.map(match => {
            return {
              id : match.id,
              title: match.title
            };
        });

        console.log(this.matchs, this.others);
    });
  }
}
```

[Online Version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ypibfb)